# setting up opengl view and projection transformations

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-es, shader

I am making some basic steps towards rendering with opengl. I wrote some shaders as well as a some math functions to do the linear algebra.

I can get a quad that's 2d tris to render on screen but when it comes to applying any sort of transformations I see nothing.

Here is the relevant code as to the matrix data that I am sending to the gpu, etc.

**setup matricies**

```
mat4identity(&vm);
vec3f eye    = {0, 0, 0};
vec3f center = {0, 0, -1};
vec3f up     = {0, 1, 0};

mat4LookAt(&vm, &eye, &center, &up);
mat4print("lookat",&vm);

mat4OrthoProjection(&opm, 200, 0, 200, 0, 0.001, 1000.0);
mat4print("2d projection",&opm);
```

**render code**

```
glUseProgram(sp);
glBindVertexArray(vao1);

pMat = getUniformLocation(sp, "proj");
vMat = getUniformLocation(sp, "view");
transMat = getUniformLocation(sp, "transform");

glUniformMatrix4dv(pMat, 1, GL_FALSE, opm.m);
glUniformMatrix4dv(vMat, 1, GL_FALSE, vm.m);
glUniformMatrix4dv(transMat, 1, GL_FALSE, tm.m);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

the mat4 is a column major struct in c.

**mat4 lookat function**

```
mat4* lookat(vec3f* eye, vec3f* center, vec3f* up) {
vec3f x = {1, 0, 0};
vec3f y = {0, 1, 0};
vec3f z = {0, 0, 1};

z = vec3fsub(eye, center);
vec3fnorm(z);
x = vec3fcross(y, z);
y = vec3fcross(z, x);
vec3fnorm(x);
vec3fnorm(y);

double x1, y1, z1;
x1 = vec3fdotr(&x, eye);
y1 = vec3fdotr(&y, eye);
z1 = vec3fdotr(&z, eye);

double data[] = { (&x)->p[0], (&y)->p[0], (&z)->p[0], 0,
                  (&x)->p[1], (&y)->p[1], (&z)->p[1], 0,
                  (&x)->p[2], (&y)->p[2], (&z)->p[2], 0,
                  x1,        y1,       z1,        1      };
return makeMat4(data);

}
```

**orthographic projection code**

```
mat4* mat4Projection(double r, double l, double t, double b, double n, double f)
{
    double data[] = { (2*n)/(r-l),  0,           (r+l)/(r-l),        0,
                       0,          (2*n)/(t-b),  (t+b)/(t-b),        0,
                       0,           0,           (-(f+n))/(f-n),     (-2*(f*n))/(f-n),
                       0,           0,           -1,                 1                };
    return makeMat4(data);
}
```

I also try to send down just a simple transform matrix that moves the objects 20 units in the +z direction. Running the above code and printing out the matrices along the way I get these results.

```
    lookat matrix
[   1.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    ]
[   0.000000    1.000000    0.000000    0.000000    ]
[   0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    0.000000    ]
[   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    ]

    2d projection matrix
[   0.010000    0.000000    0.000000    -1.000000   ]
[   0.000000    0.010000    0.000000    -1.000000   ]
[   0.000000    0.000000    -0.002000   -1.000002   ]
[   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    ]

    translation matrix  
[   1.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    ]
[   0.000000    1.000000    0.000000    0.000000    ]
[   0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    20.000000   ]
[   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    ]
```

The error could be at this line when I am sending the data to the gpu

```
glUniformMatrix4dv(pMat, 1, GL_FALSE, opm.m);
```

but again I am not sure. This is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

removing the proj and view transformations I get the rectangle in the middle of the screen. Using either projection or view transformations and I can't see anything on screen, just the clear background.

Comment: It also looks as if the project matrix function does not correspond with the output you show. In the function you set element at [row=3, column=2] to -1, but in the output it is 0. The output looks correct to me.

Comment: Other thing: You are looking along negative z-direction. When you move the object to z=20, it is located behind the camera.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @foobaz on ##opengl freenode irc channel. The issue is that opengl 3.x doesn't support doubles and my matrix as well as vector classes were double types. Switching those over to floats and the code worked just as expected.

double point precision is supported in opengl 4.5 or greater.